# Rake is out of synch with my Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I have inherited a Ruby on Rails project where the programmer didn't use rake to create the db schema, so it seems very out of synch, is there a way to rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a schema.rb file

`rake db:schema:dump`

Then make a migration ot of it.

```
class CreateMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # insert schema.rb here
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

You might also need to create the schema_migrations table, and manually add the timestamp for this migration to it.

Comment: You don't need to put the schema in a migration, it will be in `db/schema.rb` and that's good enough, as people can load it using `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: It just so that the "initial" migration would exist, and one can start a fresh with rake db:migrate as well.